# NetBeans + GWT 2.2.0 + Maven compile problem

Tags: gwt, netbeans, maven, netbeans-6.9

I'm trying to create a Maven Web Application project with Google Web Toolkit in NetBeans 6.9. I've followed the steps shown on this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-iVZ5TJ21w

After creating the project and adding GWT to the frameworks my project compiles and deploys to Tomcat nicely. Now i like to change the default GWT version from 2.0.3 to 2.2.0. As i edit the `gwt.version` property in the POM and save the file, NetBeans fetches the new `gwt-user-2.2.0.jar` file and the javadoc. However if i try to compile the project i get this Maven error in the console:

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.2.0/gwt-dev-2.2.0-linux.jar
Unable to find resource 'com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:linux:2.2.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

If i point my browser to the URL http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.2.0/ i can see that there's truly no `gwt-dev-2.2.0-linux.jar` present. However i can see there a `gwt-dev-2.2.0.jar` which i think will be the correct one to use.

What should i do to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using old version of gwt-maven-plugin. Switch to 2.2.0 or remove version declaration and it'll fetch newest version.

It's also possible that you have some old-format dependency for GWT in your pom. There used to be  tag required for old GWT versions. If you have one you can remove  tag and it will fetch system independent version without -linux suffix.

Comment: Thank you, the plugin version was the problem. It tried to use `gwt-maven-plugin` version 1.2.