# maven dependency not found in repository

Tags: gwt, maven, extjs, dependencies, gxt

I'm trying to run the project, which uses gwt-dev.
The instructions are at: http://neiliscoding.blogspot.ru/2012/05/how-to-setup-examples-for-use-in-gxt-3.html?showComment=1362999279386
when I create dependency in terminal like: `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.gwt -DartifactId=gwt-dev -Dversion=2.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile='/home/mikhail/Загрузки/libraries/gwt-2.5.0/gwt-dev.jar'`
and add dependency to the pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

maven says:

```
    [WARNING] You should not declare gwt-dev as a project dependency. This may introduce complex dependency conflicts
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.5.0/gwt-dev-2.5.0-linux-libs.zip
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:zip:linux-libs:2.5.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

else if I remove it maven says:

```
[INFO] using GWT jars from project dependencies : 2.5.0
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.5.0/gwt-dev-2.5.0-linux-libs.zip
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:zip:linux-libs:2.5.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
```

So I have Build error in both cases. How to deal with such situation? help me please.

I didn't managed with this problem yet but I've just found that I used 1.2 version of maven plugin. I'm not shure it is the main problem, but I'd like to deal with it anyway. so, sinse I've added this plugin according to your first link, maven drops build error:
`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin: checking for updates from central
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:RELEASE:generate] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing archetype:generate
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [archetype:generate {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] Archetype repository missing. Using the one from [org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1-rc1] found in catalog remote
[WARNING] Property module is missing. Add -Dmodule=someValue
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Archetype org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1-rc1 is not configured
    Property module is missing.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 12 15:18:50 MSK 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/428M
```

`
and by the way, I use intellij IDEA

Comment: The questions are: why are you manually installing GWT into your Maven repo whereas it's available on Central? (which the gwt-maven-plugin correctly downloads in the second case) and where is this `*:zip:linux-libs:*` dependency coming from? Run `mvn dependency:tree` or look at the “Dependency hierarchy” tab of your `pom.xml` in Eclipse to find out.

Comment: actually I slightly understand this yet. I began studying gwt/gxt/maven and working with them only a month ago. And I use Intellij idea only for the month too(and I can't change it to eclipse (which I'm familiar to) because my chief don't like it). and so, I need rich explanations. All this months I've been adding different features to the project which is using gxt 2.2.0. And now my chief wants me to move this applicaion to the gxt 3.0.1, os, help me please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GWT stopped maintaining separate platform dependent libs for windows,linux and mac long time ago. GWT 1.7 was the last of such platform dependent libs. So `"linux-libs"` does not make sense in your error. I am guessing you are using a really old gwt-maven-plugin .

1. Move to latest [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/).
2. Use `<scope>provided</scope>` for gwt-dev dependency to avoid it being pushed into WEB-INF/lib ( harmless but redundant )
3. Use global/central [repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) instead of installing it user repo locally.
4. You can also start off using GWT samples for maven projects [here](https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.1.zip).

Note - your query might be a duplicate/similart to [NetBeans + GWT 2.2.0 + Maven compile problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356989/netbeans-gwt-2-2-0-maven-compile-problem)

### *Edit for new GWT release*

**GWT 2.5.1** has been released and also make note **gwt-maven-plugin** is of **2.5.0** ( 1 step behind GWT :)

Comment: well, thank you. I didn't managed with this problem yet but I've just found that I used 1.2 version of maven plugin. I'm not shure it is the main problem, but I'd like to deal with it anyway. so, sinse I've added this plugin according to your first link, maven drops build error

Comment: You know, It's most likely that you are right about similarity to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356989/netbeans-gwt-2-2-0-maven-compile-problem, but I don't know how to update gwt-maven plugin in the intellij idea

Comment: Intellij Idea reads and configure from your maven plugin. Once again try referring gwt examples before configuring your pom.xml for gwt-maven-plugin. Also avoid posting comments as answer. Edit your question and post the update. Delete the answer (comment) you have posted. its a bad practice on stackoverflow :)

Comment: thank you for stackoverflow advice. About the main question. I still **don't** understand how to change gwt-maven-plugin in IDEA, but I solved the problem by just executing: `mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.1-rc1 -DgroupId=org.example.sen -DartifactId=sen -Dversion=1.0 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:generate` in the terminal and opened the project in the IDEA. So now I have another problem: I can't add dependences from repository, but only created by me(`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=....`).

Comment: Set 2.5.0 as version id for gwt-maven-plugin and for gwt dependencies set 2.5.1 as version id. Delete project from Idea and start over :)

Comment: So this `"You should not declare gwt-dev as a project dependency. This may introduce complex dependency conflicts"` is outdated advice?  Along with the advice on this page https://code.google.com/p/gwtx/wiki/GwtWithMaven?